# Apple script to Check Share iTunes Library XML with other applications

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

Is there any apple script to make

Check "Share iTunes Library XML with other applications." from

iTunes
Preferences
Advanced tab...
i want to read itunes media library .xml but in lates itunes no xml is created by default,
so i want this xml to be created by my application via apple script.
iTunes12.4

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this (created on El Capitan)

```
activate application "iTunes"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        keystroke "," using command down
        repeat until exists toolbar 1 of window 1
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        tell window 1
            if title does not contain "Advanced" then
                click button "Advanced" of toolbar 1
                repeat until its title starts with "Advanced"
                    delay 0.2
                end repeat
            end if
            tell checkbox "Share iTunes Library XML with other applications" of group 1
                if value is not 1 then
                    click it
                end if
            end tell
            click button "OK"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I am working on windows and here i require .js file,
It works fine for mac